# Algorithm for LUT inversion for flux-map problem

Tags: algorithm, lookup-tables, inversion

I have 2 Look-up tables (N-rows M-columns matrices). They describe the sampling of two two-variables functions of the type

L1 = f1(x, y) and L2 = f2(x, y)

(specifically but not fundamental, these are the fluxes of two non-linear magnetically coupled iron cores where 'x' is the current circulating of the first, 'y' is the current circulating on the second, L1 is the total flux-linkage on the 1st core and L2 is the total flux-linkage on the 2nd core).

I want to be able to find the inverse Look-up tables in order to be able to have 2 matrices of the type

x = g1(L1, L2)

y = g2(L1, L2)

The algorithm I've adopted is the following (I'm not sure it works correctly)

```
Create rows and column vectors for the maps g1 and g2 by discretizing
the intervals v1=min(L1):delta1:max(L1) and v2=min(L2):delta2:max(L2)

Solve minimization problem:
  min{ |L1(x,y) - L1*| + |L2(x,y) - L2*| }
  for each L1* and L2* find the (x,y) pairs ... 
  ... (L1* is element of v1, L2* is element of v2).

Collect all x(i) and y(i) that solve the minimization problem for L1*(i) L2*(i)

Create matrix X: num(L1*) rows, num(L2*) cols
Fill entry (L1*(i),L2*(i)) with x(i)

Create matrix Y: num(L1*) rows, num(L2*) cols
Fill entry (L1*(i),L2*(i)) with y(i)
```

Hopefully what I've written makes sense. I'd like to know if this procedure is correct or if there's a better way to solve these kind of problem (with mathematical proofs or links to papers that deal with these kind of algorithms).

Thanks in advance for your help